# Use BULK INSERT to load only some columns from a tab delimited file

Tags: sql-server, format, bulkinsert

I have a wide tab delimited file from which I only need some columns, not all. I don't want to load and parse all columns from the file - the file has more than the 1024 column accepted by SQL Server, so loading the entire file might not be a straight forward job. I am trying to BULK INSERT with a format file, so that I can extract only some columns from the file and load them into a narrow table.
For Example (over simplified), I have a table:
**T_Narrow (ID INT, var1 varchar(255), var2 varchar(255), var3 varchar(255))**
and a file with these columns
**Column1Column2...Column50**

I want to BULK INSRET from the file to T_Narrow like this:

- Table's ID - File's Column1
- Table's var1 - File's Column5
- Table's var2 - File's Column7
- Table's Var3 - File's Column7

I tried playing around with formats in a lot of ways but I cannot get what I want. I am not sure if it is even possible.

It would really help if somebody can provide a format file that will realize the scenario above.

Comment: `BULK INSERT` is an "all of nothing" process. If you need to be picky about the columns, you'll need to use something else. Alternatively, load your data into a sparse table (which can have up to 30,000 columns) and then `INSERT` the data from that into your production table.

Comment: Why not just load them into a staging table that has all the columns (and you can get more than 1024, as Thom said), and then insert to the narrow table from the staging table? Or write a parser in C# / PowerShell / Python that digests the original file and spits out the one you wanted. Or have the process that creates the file in the first place spit out two different files.

Comment: @ThomA I think you can just use a format file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Gave it a quick go, and i just get `Cannot bulk load. Invalid column number in the format file "C:\temp\Data.fmt".` or `Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\temp\Data.fmt" is incomplete or could not be read. Operating system error code (null).` errors, @Charlieface .

Comment: @ThomA Make sure the first value of each line in the format file is the column order of the text file. And the second header line should be the total number of columns in the text file

Comment: Either way, we need to see a table definition and sample text file to be able to answer this question

Comment: Different error now. Seems that it's trying to insert the values of my second and third columns from the text file (rather than just the 3rd) into the 2nd column in the table, as I'm trying to omit the second column from the text file. If you know how to do this with a format file, I'd love to see an answer, @Charlieface , as they're not something I use often.

Comment: Just realized I don't think this is going to work because you are reading from the same column in the data file twice. You might need to leave one of them out and update afterwards